# How to avoid excessive code duplication when using enums in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding, superclass

I am refactoring some legacy code and have come across a problem which I'm sure has a elegant solution - but I can't quite get there.

Initially there were a load of classes which extended an abstract class `BaseType`.  Each of these classes has a enum - `XmlElementTag` - with values specific to the class:

```
enum XmlElementTag {value1, value2, value3}
```

They each also have a method :

```
private XmlElementTag getTag(String s){
    XmlElementTag ret = null;
    try {
        ret = XmlElementTag.valueOf(s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this, s+" is not supported tag");
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Every class has this exact same `getTag` method, but obviously they are all referring to the `XmlElementTag` enum specific to the class they are in.  So, I'd like to get rid of this code duplication if I can.

I thought that maybe I could use a marker interface to solve this problem, so created one as which each `XmlElementTag` enum now inherits and rewrote the `getTag` method and put it in the super class.

So I have this in each class:

```
private XmlElementTag implements GenericTag {value1, value2, value3};
```

And this in the BaseType superclass:

```
public interface GenericTag {}

protected GenericTag getTag(String tagName){
    XmlElementTag tag = null;
    try {
        tag = XmlElementTag.valueOf(tagName);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(this, tagName+" is not supported tag");
    }
    return tag;
}
```

But again this doesn't work as the `BaseType` super class doesn't know what `XmlElementTag` is; Java doesn't allow abstract class variables; and creating this element in the `BaseType` won't work, as the `getTag` code will always refer to this enum, rather than the one in the class which extends `BaseType`.

Can anyone point me in the correct direction?

Comment: you *can* have abstract types in java.

Comment: i mean abstract class variables - will update to reflect this.

Comment: Please remove the Android tag, as this is a general Java question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Java enums don't come with a good meta-class (`Class` is evil). However, all you really need here is the list (array) of the enum values.

As it's a private method, you might as well use composition.

```
import static java.util.Objects.requireNonNull;

/* pp */ class EnumFinder<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final E[] tags;
    protected BaseType(E[] tags) {
        this.tags = requireNonNull(tags);
    }

    public E getTag(String name) {
        requireNonNull(name);
        for (E tag : tags) {
            if (name.equals(tag.name())) {
                return tag;
            }
        }
        Log.e(this, name+" is not supported tag"); // (sic)
        return null; // (sic)
    }
    ...
}

public class DerivedType {
    private static final EnumFinder<XmlElementType> finder = // note, shared
        new EnumFinder<>(XmlElementType.values());
    ...
        finder.getTag(name)
    ...
}
```

(Create a `Map<String,E>` if you really want to. Unnecessary for reasonably sized enums.)

If you really want to use inheritance, then that is much the same. (Unfortunately as we are using an array, unless you add more boilerplate to your code, this code will create an unnecessary extra array per instance - probably not a significant issue, but may be.):

```
/* pp */ abstract class BaseType<E extends Enum<E>> {
    private final E[] tags;
    protected BaseType(E[] tags) {
        this.tags = requireNonNull(tags);
    }

    public E getTag(String name) {
        requireNonNull(name);
        for (E tag : tags) {
            if (name.equals(tag.name())) {
                return tag;
            }
        }
        Log.e(this, name+" is not supported tag"); // (sic)
        return null; // (sic)
    }
    ...
}
public class DerivedType extends BaseType<XmlElementType> {
    public DerivedType() {
        super(XmlElementType.values());
    }
    ...
        this.getTag(name)
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is looking good!  One not - In the first example you use the class name EnumFinder, I assume this is a cut&paste error and should be BaseType?

Comment: @Martyn copy&paste error was that in the composition example, `DerivedType` should not have extended `BaseType`. (I wrote the second version first.)

Comment: But you're defining class EnumFinder followed by a constructor for BaseType. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3):

You might be able to coalesce the `XmlElementTag` elements into a single `enum` and establish an [`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) apropos to each derived type. There's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559163/stopping-repetition-in-java-enums/6559541#6559541).

Addendum: In this scheme, `getTag()` would then become a single method of the combined `enum`. Each derived class would invoke `getTag()` using the `Set` that it considers valid. The method might have a signature such as this:

```
public static XmlElementTag getTag(Set valid, String s) { ... }
```

Answer (score 3):

I guess you could write a static generic helper method that did what `getTag` does.  It would need to use reflection under the hood, and would most likely require you to pass the enumeration's `Class` object as a parameter.

But IMO, you shouldn't.  The `getTag()` method is kind of wrong-headed.  It is turning what is effectively bad input into a `null`.  That's wrong from two perspectives:

- In most contexts, "you gave me bad stuff" should not be treated as "you gave me nothing".
- If you are not scrupulously careful, those `null` values are going to come back to bite you as `NullPointerException`s.

So really, your application code should either catch and deal with the `IllegalArgumentException` that arises when the conversion goes wrong, or it should allow the exception to bubble up to the top where it can be reported as (for instance) an error parsing the input stream.

(I don't think that an `enum` can either extend or be extended, so I don't think your `enum`s can inherit a generic version of this class.)

Comment: I agree with the remark that `getTag()` is wrong-headed. Yet, I find interesting the question on *how to implement only once a method whose signature depends on the concrete class*.

Comment: I wouldn't have written this method as it currently stands but I don't want to make any changes which may introduce bugs whilst I'm refactoring.  If I had my way most of the code base would be removed and rewritten!

Answer (score 1):

You could use [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/language/generics.html) for that:

The Base is

```
public abstract class Base {
protected static <T extends Enum<T>> T getTag(Class<T> enumType, String s) {
    T ret = null;
    try {
        ret = Enum.valueOf(enumType, s);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println(s + " is not supported tag");
    }
    return ret;
}

protected abstract <T extends Enum<T>> T getTag(String s);
}
```

Your numerous classes have a shorter `getTag()` (and all the logic is in the `Base`)

```
public class ClassA extends Base {
enum XmlElementTag {
    UL, LI
}

@Override
protected XmlElementTag getTag(String s) {
    return Base.getTag(XmlElementTag.class, s);
}
}
```

(same thing for `ClassB`)

Comment: True - doing this crossed my mind but ideally I'd like to be able to completely remove the duplicated code.  This method would still see duplication which is an issue as I have lots of classes extending the Base, although the extend of the duplication is obviously much less.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you wanted to achieve something like this (correct me if I'm wrong):

```
interface GenericTag {

    public GenericTag fromString(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException;
}


class BaseType {

    protected GenericTag getTag(String tagName) {
        GenericTag tag = null;
        try {
            tag = tag.fromString(tagName); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(this, tagName+" tag is not supported");
        }
        return tag;
    }

}

class ConcreteTypeA extends BaseType {

    enum XmlElementTag implements GenericTag {
        TAG1, TAG2;

        public GenericTag fromString(String str) throws IllegalArgumentException {
            return XmlElementTag.valueOf(str);
        }
    }
}
```

However, that will never work. You would need the fromString method to return an instance of appropriate class (in this case, enum) implementing the GenericTag, but the fromString method has to be performed by that concrete class, which you don't have yet, so you'll get a NullPointerException.
It's a sort of Chicken and Egg Problem! :)

Comment: Yeah - wish Java would allow abstract class members, would make it much easier!