# Constructing an if statement that checks enums on a list

Tags: java, arrays, enums, if-statement

What would be the most efficent to check if something is on a list of enums? I've looked around for a while and it wasn't very clear. Arrays don't have a contains() function and hashmaps are key:value.

Something like:

```
if(enumlist.contains(foo.enum())){
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: See also "Item 32: Use `EnumSet` instead of bit fields"—[Effective Java](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/effective/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`List#indexOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#indexOf%28java.lang.Object%29).

```
if (enumList.indexOf(foo) > -1) {
    // go crazy
}
```

Alternately, you can use the (extremely efficient) [`EnumSet` data structure](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) to store the objects — if you're okay with not being able to store duplicate elements.

```
if (enumSet.contains(foo)) {
    // just, like, whatever, man
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[`EnumSet`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) has a suitable `contains()` method.

Addendum: Using this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6559163/stopping-repetition-in-java-enums/6559541#6559541), the following prints `true`.

```
System.out.println(Resolution.deluxe.contains(Resolution.RES_256));
```