# Working with enum types in java

Tags: java, data-structures, enums

I need to create a "super" enum (here `ESideItem`) which will keep record of "sub" enums (`SALAD`, `FRY`, `TACO`) & I need to access "sub" enum's fields(`price`) from outside too.
I meant "super" as main type & "sub" as sub-type of that main type.
There can be many types of SideItems (FRY, SALAD, TACO) for a meal  & each of these sideitems can be of many types (i.e SALAD can be CHICKEN or AFGHAN or MIMOSA etc).

Following **Ray Tayek**'s answer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7296785/using-nested-enum-types-in-java#answer-7399540) question I've implemented this:

```
public abstract class SideItem {

public enum FRY {
    FRENCHFRY(25.25f), SEASONEDCURLYFRY(30.10f);

    private float  price;

    FRY(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

public enum SALAD{
    AFGHANSALAD(50.25f), CHICKENSALAD(40.10f), MIMOSASALAD(45.89f);

    private float  price;

    SALAD(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

public enum TACO{
    MONSTERTACO(26.25f), NACHOMONSTERTACO(35.10f);

    private float  price;

    TACO(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }


    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}

public enum ESideItem {
    FRY(SideItem.FRY.FRENCHFRY), SALAD(SideItem.SALAD.AFGHANSALAD), TACO(SideItem.TACO.MONSTERTACO);

    ESideItem(Enum e) {
        this.e = e;
    }

    public Object[] subValues() {
        return e.getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants();
    }

    final Enum e;

}
}
```

I implementd `Main.java`  as follows:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    for(SideItem.ESideItem aSideItem : SideItem.ESideItem.values()){
        System.out.println(aSideItem);
        for(Object o : aSideItem.subValues()){
            System.out.format("%-15s",o);
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println();
    }
}
}
```

The output is:

```
FRY
FRENCHFRY      
SEASONEDCURLYFRY

SALAD
AFGHANSALAD    
CHICKENSALAD   
MIMOSASALAD    

TACO
MONSTERTACO    
NACHOMONSTERTACO
```

`Main.java` is like client side & `SideItem.java` is like server side. I can change or add any instance in the `ESubItem` enum from `SideItem.java`. `Main.java` should give output according to that change 
But I do need to get price of these individual TACO's, SALAD's, FRY's  .
 Is there any way to access these fields from `Main.java` using enum? 
If not then what kind of data structure should I use to solve this problem ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve. Do you want all enums to implement a common interface that provides a `getPrice()` method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be using an interface:

```
interface Food
{
    float getPrice();
}

public enum Fry implements Food 
{
    FRENCH_FRY(25.25f), SEASONED_CURLY_FRY(30.10f);

    private final float price;

    FRY(float price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

    @Override
    public float getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
}
```

And the same for the other two...

Then you can compose them like so:

```
public enum Meal implements Food {
    HAPPY_MEAL(Fry.FRENCH_FRY, Fry.SEASONED_CURLY_FRY),
    SAD_MEAL(Salad.AFGHAN_SALAD);

    private final List<Food> items;

    Meal (Food... items) {
        this.items = Arrays.asList(food);
    }

    @Override
    public float getPrice()
    {
        return (float) items.stream().mapToDouble(Food::getPrice).sum();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access the price for calculations etc. the easiest way is to make all those enums implement an interface with `public float getPrice()`.

For display purposes you would only need to modify the `toString()` of each enum.

The `enum ESideItem` and `SideItem` classes seem unnecessary though. Especially the `ESideItem` doesn't seem like it should be an `enum` at all, and the way you're using `getDeclaringClass().getEnumConstants()` is just a really bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to something like:

```
for(Object o : aSideItem.subValues()){
    if(o instanceof SideItem.FRY)
    ((SideItem.FRY)o).getPrice()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define an interface, say

```
public interface Priced {
    double getPrice();
}
```

The enums can implement that

```
public enum FRY implements Priced { // no further change needed, method already there
```

and you can return an array of `Priced` with your `subValues()`.

```
public Priced[] subValues() {
    return Stream.of(FRY.values(), SALAD.values(), TACO.values()).
           toArray(Priced[]::new);
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if the latter works this way, but being able to implement an interface in your `enum` is the main point.