# Efficeint way to manipulate multiple Checkbox items

Tags: java, swing, performance, jcheckbox

I have a 6 JCheckBoxes in the UI and based one some user operations, I have to change the state of the JCheckBoxes, like enabling,selecting and making it invisible. So, instead of having the code as separate for each JCheckBox, I have used the following code,

```
  Object[] checkBoxCollection = null;
        checkBoxCollection = new Object[]{qualityChkBox1, qualityChkBox2, qualityChkBox3, qualityChkBox4, qualityChkBox5, qualityChkBox6};
        for (int i = 0; i < checkBoxCollection.length; i++) {
            JCheckBox checkBox = (JCheckBox) checkBoxCollection[i];
            if (checkBox.getText().equals("Name") || checkBox.getText().equals("RollNo")) {
                checkBox.setSelected(true);
            } else {
                checkBox.setSelected(false);
            }
        }
```

Similarly, I have some places in code, where I am keep on changing the state like `setSelected(false)` and `setSelected(true)`.

Is there any way that I can do more better than this ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use JCheckBox array instead of Object array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6559541/230513), you may be able to use `EnumSet` to define sets that represent coherent states of your model. Then your check boxes can share a common [`Action`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) that conditions each `JCheckBox` according to that defined state.